# Fill another empty chest using hopper without repeater

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Most faction servers I've been to don't allow repeaters.

So say I have 3 chests and hoppers (denoted by the symbol `V`)

```
[  brewing stand ]
         V
[     chest 3    ]
         V
[     chest 2    ]
         V
[     chest 1    ]
```

I know chest 1 will be full and I want to start filling up 2 and so on.

But with this construction, the items always go down to the last hopper until the last hopper is filled up then 2nd hopper is used.

Any way to improve this system without repeater :/ ? Thanks

Comment: are you able to use comparitors

Comment: whats the problem, isnt it ok if chest 2 only fills as soon as chest 1 is full?

Comment: i presume he has the hoppers alongside the chests. and it ends up just filling the hoppers and not the top two chests. a screenshot would be really helpful

Comment: Screenshot won't help because the problem is pretty clear.. at least I think it is. Chest 1 is filled up, but before chest 2 can be used to fill up more items, the hopper above chest1 has to be filled up (all slots). So I will waste many items (potions in this case).

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to using redstone to do this, would be to line up the chests and use a hopper minecart to run over the top of the chests to move back and forth over the top of the chests, this will fill up all of the chests over time. and then you just can put the brewing stand on top of another hopper to feed the cart. Ignore the repeaters in this picture, the same thing could be accomplished with comparitors and normal redstone.

[image: example]
[V] = Hopper Minecart

> ```
>                                   Brewing
>                             _____ V
> ```
>
> _[V]___________________________/
>
> [Chest] [Chest] [Chest] [Chest]

Comment: I'd agree to this or a similar setup if you want items distributed into multiple chests; one caveat is that this will distribute the items evenly over all chests depending on input into the hopper cart and the path of the tracks relative to the filling point (straight path going back and forth, or round-trip in a loop), but its not too much of a big deal imo.

Comment: I don't know exactly what he is using it for but by the sounds of it he is producing a single type of item and it doesn't matter how the chests get filled but that they get filled in that situation

Comment: Well I guess there is no way to do it then :( timing devices are always disabled on my faction server. But thanks for trying. Upvote (but can't check since this is not a valid answer due to the server constraint).

Comment: Actually I can't even upvote because I am still 1..

Comment: this would work you don't need timing devices you can just use direct current

Comment: I agree with Flaunting; you can create a looped track with powered rails to keep the hopper cart moving, passing underneath a hopper from the brewing stand, passing over the chests, then completing the loop back to the brewing stand. There is no timing required.

Comment: The only thing that i would do without the restriction is have a timed delay to the minecart starting again between chests so it drops everything so that the chests fill up in order